# query database into associative array codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter-3

I want to make a data conversion, by fetching an existing query in the database

```
$konv =  $this->db->get('konversi')->result_array();
    
  foreach ($konv as $result) {
        $konv_data[$result['kata']] = $result['konversi'] . ",";
  }


 $descc = strtr($data['description'], $konv_data);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
$konv =  $this->db->get('konversi')->result_array();
```

to

```
$konv =  $this->db->get('konversi')->result();
```

You are getting result as associative array by using te result() method.